# Packaging files into single HTML/webapp?

Tags: file, web

I have 100 images and a JSON file that i'd like to pack into a single file
Something like a .MHT file but not windows-centric.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Zip them. Problem solved. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Chrome doesn't allow ajax requests to file://